# C++ friend function declaration between two seperate files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've been instructed to create two Classes: Customer and Barber,
Barber should have a function : cutHair() that can change the value of private member hairLength in Customer.

Customer.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_H
#define CUSTOMER_H
#include "barber.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;  

class Customer{
    public:
        friend void Barber::cutHair(Customer &someGuy);
        Customer(string name, double hairLength);
        string getName();
        double getHair();
        void setHair(double newHair);
    private:
        string name;
        double hairLength;
};
#endif
```

Barber.h

```
#ifndef BARBER_H
#define BARBER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "customer.h"
using namespace std;
class Customer;
class Barber{
    public:
        Barber(string barberName);
        void cutHair(Customer &someGuy);
    private:
        string name;
        double takings;
};
#endif
```

barber.cpp **EDIT: I changed the implementation of cutHair() to take advantage of the friend declaration instead of accessing the private members of class Customer through it's public accessor methods**

```
#include "barber.h"
#include <string>

Barber::Barber(string barberName){
        name = barberName;
        takings = 0;
}
void Barber::cutHair(Customer &someGuy){
        takings += 18;
        someGuy.hairLength = someGuy.hairLength * 80 / 100; 
}
```

customer.cpp

```
#include "customer.h"
#include <string>

Customer::Customer(string customerName, double custHairLength){
        name = customerName;
        hairLength = custHairLength;
}
double Customer::getHair(){
        return hairLength;
}
void Customer::setHair(double newLength){
        hairLength = newLength;
}
```

when attemping to build i get the error message

```
customer.h(10): error C2653: 'Barber' : is not a class or namespace name
```

been doing research and canceling out issues one after another for a few days now.
hope someone can come to my rescue :)

Comment: Are you required to use friendship to solve the problem? Could you implement a solution not using friendship?

Comment: Why are you making the Barber method a friend? In the definition of the method, the Barber calls public methods and never touches any private or protected part of the Customer.

Comment: You're right, the requirement was to get the access via friend fucntion.
I changed the code to access it via private member and not through the public classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Barber.h` you are forward declaring Customer (`class Customer;`) AND including `#include Customer.h"`. Try removing the include. Of course you will have to add the include in your `Barber.cpp`

Comment: Great, been really helpful!
More hopeful about enjoying c++ programming now :)

Answer (score 3):

You have cyclic dependency here. You include barber.h from customer.h and customer.h from barber.h.

In barber.h use

```
class Customer;
```

instead of

```
#include "customer.h"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.
it was a combination of both your advice and Drahakar's
saying i will have to add the include in your Barber.cpp

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out
i forgot about this feature, its my first post here :)
For the sake of accuracy i accepted Drahakar's advice because it referred to both issues. 
Is it possible to accept more than one answer?

Comment: That's ok ;-) No, there is no way to do that

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a forward declaration such as `class Customer` in `Barber.h`, you are telling the compiler if you see the name Customer ignore it for now at declaration as long as you don't need to know the size of the object. However in your case when you are declaring the `CutHair` function you are using the actual `Customer` object in the argument.  If you change the code in a way to have the pointer to `Customer` as the argument, and get rid of the inclusion dependencies, your code will compile.

I would also suggest that in your case you wouldn't need a friend function if you had a `setHair` function defined, unless you have a good reason not to have that function.